# Git configuration for using an external merge tool for binary

Tags: git, binary, diff, external

How can I use git with external merge tool for binaries?

I have already added the following configuration in git gitconfig:
[image: gitconfiguration for an external merge tool]

I want to merge 2 branches together with a mergeconflict.
For this I have tried the command "git merge branchname" in git bash.

[image: git bash reply]

Git replies me, with a (expected) merge conflict,
but how can I automated open directly my mergetool after a conflict?

Git should try to resolve my mergeconflict with my defined tool in gitconfig.
Because my defined tool can merge/diff and handle the binaries.

Have anyone an idea how can i resolve this problem?
I didn't find a suitable git hook.
The git hook "pre-merge" invoked only if the merge are successful.

Comment: When I call `git mergetool`, it prompts me for which tool to use. Does it work if you type the name of your merge tool there? Or is that what you're trying to avoid having to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I would like to call only git merge, and if there is any conflict, git should call my mergetool. But this requires two steps. First call "git merge" and then "git mergetool". 
I have worked with mercurial before and in mercurial is this only one step. I was hoping git would be similar. It is a little bit more comfortable, if scm calls automatically the mergetool if its needed.

Comment: OK, I see where you're going. There might be some GUIs that could do this integration for you, but I've never used any. I'm a command-line guy to the core, and I like the control I get from having to call each step myself as I see fit, so I won't be able to help you.